# How to calculate date between different fields in two querysets with same foreign key in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am using Django.
Is there a way to count between different fields in a queryset with the same foreign key??!!

That is, we want to subtract register_date from injection_date.
You want to get (2021-1-03) - (2021-10-31) = 3days.

| injection_date | enroll_date | student_id (외래키) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-31 |  | 52 |
|  | 2021-11-03 | 52 |

Below is the code I've written so far, how do I fix it?! Please help.
[models.py]

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    ...

class Feedback(models.Model):
    injection_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    enroll_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

[views.py]

```
injection_enroll = Feedback.objects\
          .annotate(enroll_injection=F('enrolL_date') - F('injection_date'))
```

Comment: Can you share your model? Could the same student have multiple values for one of the fields?

Comment: Don't get it... Two different fields and one FK...?? Can you explain and share the model...??

Comment: Fully edited. Thanks again for watching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you all students annotated with their max enroll_date minus their min injection_date. The min/max is for removing duplicate values that may occur for a student

```
Student.objects.annotate(
    injection_date=Min('feedback__injection_date'),
    enroll_date=Max('feedback__enroll_date')
).annotate(
    enroll_injection=F('enroll_date') - F('injection_date')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField, F
from django.db.models.functions import Cast, ExtractDay, TruncDate


injection_enroll = Feedback.objects.annotate(
    enroll_injection=Cast(
        ExtractDay(TruncDate(F('enrolL_date')) - TruncDate(F('injection_date'))),
        IntegerField()
    )
)
```

Comment: {'studnet_id': 52, 'enroll_date': , 'injection_date': '2021-10-31'}
{'studnet_id': 52, 'enroll_date': '2021-11-03' , 'injection_date': } The above expression does not apply because one field has a value of null .

Comment: you need to replace it with some date if it is null or you need to filter when the field is not null

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I want to calculate in two querysets rather than in one queryset.